# Reset Bootstrap loading state button when AJAX call is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple AJAX request and I'm wondering if it's possible to combine the loading state button with my request. Is it possible to make the button reset to default when the request is completed, instead of choosing for example 5 seconds before reset as per now?

**Loading state button**

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    $btn.button('loading');
    // simulating a timeout
    setTimeout(function () {
        $btn.button('reset');
    }, 1000);
});
```

**AJAX request**

```
  $(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'html',
        url: '/m/core/_processEditEntry.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          $(".message").fadeIn(0);
          $(".message").delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
        }
      });

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to keep your code in the same place. Remove the click handler and add these lines to the ajax call:

```
  $(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      //save button so we can use later
      var my_button = $(this).find("button");

      //give button loading state
      my_button.button('loading');

      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'html',
        url: '/m/core/_processEditEntry.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {

          //reset state
          my_button.button('reset');

          $(".message").fadeIn(0);
          $(".message").delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
        }
      });

    });

  });
```

Comment: You'll also want to make sure you setup an error handler and reset the button state in there too. Otherwise, an error with the AJAX request will cause your button to get stuck in the loading state. Probably obvious, but I figured it was worth mentioning for completeness.

Comment: I just noticed your code interferes with TinyMce, the toolbar buttons seems to be "loading" too, do you know why?

Comment: I would guess that's because the code above targets all forms and any buttons within them. Making those selectors more specific will likely fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a span with a class to the button when it was clicked

```
  if ($(this).is(".btn, .page-link, .df-link")) {
              // disable button
              $(".btn").prop("disabled", true);
              // add spinner to button
              $(this).html(
                `<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> ` + $(this).text()
              );
          }
```

and then in Ajax complete remove that element:

```
complete: function(response) {
                $(".btn").prop("disabled", false);
                $(".spinner-border").remove();
            }
```